# Parsing command line arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-arguments

I would like my python program to parse command like arguments like this:

```
python dosomething.py z a1 b1 a2 b2 ...
```

where I can have any number of a# b# pairs and z is an unrelated number. If necessary I am OK with specifying the number of a and b pairs.

I'm using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).

Comment: I guess you could read z and get it out of the way, then read the rest of arguments in order (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027028/argparse-argument-order) and error out if their number is odd.

Comment: you should be able to read the rest using ``nargs='+'`` and then can use a custom action to check for even pairs. and as @deshko mentioned the first positional argument can be specified as z with ``nargs=1``

check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174975/argparse-doesnt-check-for-positional-arguments for the choice on nargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to define a [custom action](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) for such specialized behavior.

```
import sys
import argparse

class AbsAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if len(values) % 2 == 0:
            # If valid, store the values.
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

            # You could convert the flat list to a list of 2-tuples, if needed:
            #   zip(values[::2], values[1::2])
        else:
            # Otherwise, invoke a parser error with a message.
            parser.error('abs must be supplied as pairs')


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('z')
ap.add_argument('abs', nargs = '+', action = AbsAction)
opt = ap.parse_args()
print opt
```

Comment: Thanks, I combined that with a slight hack to parse the 'a' 'b' combinations and now errors are handled gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

def main(args):
    print args[0]
    print len(args)
    print [arg for arg in args]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I would like to stick with argparse if possible.